# ImageView Showing White Image Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I am trying to display an image in my app, but it isn't getting displayed. Only a white square is displayed in place of the image. Here is the `ImageView` part of my `xml`:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/calcImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="222dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:layout_marginBottom="364dp"
        android:background="@drawable/calc"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/appName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Full `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appName"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:text="Calc"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.886"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.414" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/calcImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/calc"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/appName"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Image in `@drawable/calc`:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

P.S: I have referred to similar questions on `Stack Overflow`, but they didn't solve my problem. If my question has already been asked, apologies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to exchange this line

```
android:background="@drawable/calc"
```

to

```
android:src="@drawable/calc"
```

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: try to temporary remove all margins and check then. if still won't work then try to strip another params, remove all with `layout_constraint` prefix. `layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/appName"` - this is pointing on some `appName` `View` - maybe its wrongly positioned? can you post whole XML layout?

Comment: Ok...I will post the whole `xml`

Comment: Edited...Check it out

Comment: at first `android:background` -> `android:src`, thats for shure... as a background you may use e.g. `"#098712"` (or any other random) and then you will see if image drawable isn't loading (only background color visible) or whole view isn't present (no image and no color at all). also you may try to set fixed size for both width and height. and finally this still look supsicious to me: `layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/appName"` - try to exchange value to `"parent"`

Comment: Works out for `#098712`

Comment: so there is a problem with drawable itself, `View` is aligning fine. where is placed your image file, in which folder?

Comment: My image is under `res - drawable - calc`

Comment: try to move it to `drawable-mdpi` folder, thats only a guess, as imho all should work fine... eventually you may add `android:scaleType="centerInside"` for `ImageView`, maybe this will help

Comment: Oh yeah. I was importing the image in a wrong way. My bad! Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to remove those padding first?
Like

```xml
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/calcImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/calc"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/appName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Your margin is quite large, or can you paste what you see in LayoutInspector (better with the imageView's parameters)

Comment: Still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:src="@drawable/calc"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
```

Comment: Still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

maybe your image is in drawable-v21 folder.

check your image directory with **windows explorer**